# jQuery auto complete crashed when addin EasyUI in

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

Please see my example in http://jsfiddle.net/7c84b/
Without EasyUI, auto complete works fine.
But when adding EasyUI js in, auto complete not work any more.

Please help how to make them work together peacefully.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem. A quick remedy is place the link `jquery.easyui.min.js` before the link to `jquery.ui.autocomplete.js`.